# Setuid bit on python script : Linux vs Solaris

Tags: python, linux, solaris, setuid

I am running this small python script on both linux and Solaris **as a not privileged user** :

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import os
print 'uid,euid =',os.getuid(),os.geteuid()
```

Before running, the setuid bit is set on the script (not on python interpreter) :

```
chown root:myusergrp getuid.py
chmod 4750 getuid.py
```

On Solaris, the effective uid is set because of the setuid bit :

```
uid,euid = 10002 0
```

But not on Linux :

```
uid,euid = 10002 10002
```

Note the python version is 2.6 for both Solaris and Linux

Is it possibe to have Python Linux working as Python Solaris ?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Most Unix distributions normally don't allow you to use setuid on a file that uses a #! interpreter. Solaris happens to be one that allows it due to its use of a more secure implementation than most other distributions.

See this FAQ entry for more background about why the mechanism is so dangerous: [How can I get setuid shell scripts to work?](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part4/section-7.html)

See this link for more discussion and how to compile a setuid executable that will run your script: [setuid on shell scripts](http://www.tuxation.com/setuid-on-shell-scripts.html)

The pertinent part:

```
int main()
{
   setuid( 0 );
   system( "/path/to/script.sh" );

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Solaris is based on SVR4, which as your FAQ link notes, uses more secure ways than older Unixes to handle setuid script startup.

Comment: What if your python script needs to be started as non-root user, and then suid during execution at some point?

Comment: You need to start as root and then temporarily drop privileges to the user before resuming root. See this question for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8499296/realuid-saved-uid-effective-uid-whats-going-on

Answer (score 2):

I just put two and two together today and came up with an alternative solution: [`cython --embed`](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/EmbeddingCython).

Follow the examples at the link above and you'll get binary executables from your Python that you'll be able to `chown` and `chmod u+s`, completing the circle without a wrapper program.

Of course, beware the risks (of this or any other `setuid` use)—bugs in your script can result in elevated privileges on the system.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [David K. Hess](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1055722/david-k-hess) answer, but with arguments:

```c
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    setuid(0);
    execv("/path/to/script.sh", argv);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You could potentially use sudo to achieve what you want.  It runs stuff as different users:

```
 sudo -u otheruser command
```

Permissions are set by root using visudo.  The setuid/setguid stuff doesn't appear to apply to scripts or the shell in linux, only compiled code.

Comment: Setuid bit used exactly to avoid privilege escalation