# Strange result when running a program as a root

Tags: c, linux, ubuntu

Here's a full source of a program that demonstrates my problem
(the OS is Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit if it matters):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
   int status, fd;

   printf("CURRENT UID: %d, CURRENT GID: %d\n", getuid(), getgid());

   fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_WRONLY);
   if(fd < 0)
   {
      printf("Error opening /dev/ttyS0: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      return 1;
   }
   printf("Successfully opened /dev/ttyS0\n");
   close(fd);

   /* DROP PRIVILEGES */

   setgid(1000);
   setuid(1000);

   printf("CURRENT UID: %d, CURRENT GID: %d\n", getuid(), getgid());

   fd = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_WRONLY);
   if(fd < 0)
   {
      printf("Error opening /dev/ttyS0: %s\n", strerror(errno));
      return 1;
   }
   printf("Successfully opened /dev/ttyS0\n");
   return 0;
}
```

There are two users in the system: root and a regular, non-root user (let's call him "ubuntu") with id=1000. The above program is trying to open a serial port (/dev/ttyS0) twice: first time as root or ubuntu (depending on how it's invoked) and second time always as ubuntu. First unsuccessful attempt causes the program to abort. User ubuntu is a member of dialout group so theoretically he has necessary permissions to open /dev/ttyS0. I invoke the program in four different ways:

1) run directly as ubuntu

invocation:

<path to my program>

2) run as ubuntu, but using sudo

invocation:

sudo -u ubuntu <path to my program>

3) run as root, but with privileges dropped to those of ubuntu
(so, effectively, run as ubuntu):

invocation:

sudo su
sudo -u ubuntu <path to my program>

In all three cases I get the following expected result:

```
CURRENT UID: 1000, CURRENT GID: 1000
Successfully opened /dev/ttyS0

CURRENT UID: 1000, CURRENT GID: 1000
Successfully opened /dev/ttyS0
```

In the last case, however, something strange happens:

4) run directly as root

invocation:

sudo su
<path to my program>

result:

```
CURRENT UID: 0, CURRENT GID: 0
Successfully opened /dev/ttyS0

CURRENT UID: 1000, CURRENT GID: 1000
Error opening /dev/ttyS0: Permission denied
```

Of course it's the last two lines of the output that I don't understand: this time, when root drops his privileges, it turns out that ubuntu has insufficient privileges to open /dev/ttyS0, but why? How is this case different from cases 1-3?

One last thing worth mentioning: if I change this line of my code:

```
setgid(1000);
```

to this:

```
setgid(20); /* 20 is the id of dialout group */
```

then the last attempt to open /dev/ttyS0 is successful as well.

Does it mean the information about ubuntu being a member of dialout group gets lost for some reason when I run the program as root and then drop privileges to those of ubuntu by changing uid and gid to 1000? Can you please give me a detailed explanation of what happens in case 4 of my example and why the result is different than I expected?

Comment: Google "real and effective user ID". Or [see this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32455684/difference-between-real-user-id-effective-user-id-and-saved-user-id).

Comment: Do you see the same results using `seteuid` and `setegid`?

Comment: If I substitute all occurrences of UID, GID, getuid(), getgid(), setuid(1000), and setgid(1000) with EUID, EGID, geteuid(), getegid(), seteuid(1000) and setegid(1000) respectively, the result remains exactly the same in all four cases.

Answer (score 2):

Setting the userid and groupid does *not* set all supplementary groups (i.e. all groups, which are not the main group of the user but assigned to him in `/etc/groups`) automagically. Try to use

```
initgroups("ubuntu", 1000);
```

prior to the `setgid()`-call. Then the process should have the privileges of the *dialout*-group.

Comment: Thanks, this must be the exact reason why my approach failed. Apparently David Schwartz' and tkausi's suggestions it had something to do with euid/egid were wrong.