# What is the difference between calling `id -G` and `id -G -r`?

Tags: unix

I know the `-r` flag should print the real group the user is in. But since `-G` already prints all his groups, does this make a difference?

Answer (score 0):

`-r` switches from displaying effective (default) to real identity (no matter whether group or user).  [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32456814/1281485) you can learn about the difference between the two.