# Using chown command in ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, chown

I have a command in ubuntu as

```
  sudo chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
```

I want to convert into ansible script. I have tried below

```
- name: Changing ownership
      command: chown $(id -u):$(id -g) $HOME/.kube/config
      become: true
```

but i am getting error as below

> fatal: [ubuntu]: FAILED! => {"changed": t> fatal: [ubuntu]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": ["chown", "$(id",
>   "-u):$(id", "-g)", "$HOME/.kube/config"], "delta": "0:00:00.003948",
>   "end": "2019-07-17 07:22:31.798773", "msg": "non-zero return code",
>   "rc": 1, "start": "2019-07-17 07:22:31.794825", "stderr": "chown:
>   invalid option -- 'u'\nTry 'chown --help' for more information.",
>   "stderr_lines": ["chown: invalid option -- 'u'", "Try 'chown --help'
>   for more information."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}rue, "cmd": ["chown", "$(id",
>   "-u):$(id", "-g)", "$HOME/.kube/config"], "delta": "0:00:00.003948",
>   "end": "2019-07-17 07:22:31.798773", "msg": "non-zero return code",
>   "rc": 1, "start": "2019-07-17 07:22:31.794825", "stderr": "chown:
>   invalid option -- 'u'\nTry 'chown --help' for more information.",
>   "stderr_lines": ["chown: invalid option -- 'u'", "Try 'chown --help'
>   for more information."], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}

**EDIT:**
File module also did not work.

```
  - name: Create a symbolic link
    file:
      path: $HOME/.kube
      owner: $(id -u)
      group: $(id -g)
```

Comment: Why don't you use the ansible `file` module with `owner`and `group` options?

Comment: Here id of user and group is fetched dynamically. How can i do the same

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Assuming the file already exists and you just want to change permissions, you can retrieve user ID and group from Ansible facts and do something like:

```
- name: Change kubeconfig file permission
  file:
    path: $HOME/.kube/config 
    owner: "{{ ansible_effective_user_id }}"
    group: "{{ ansible_effective_group_id }}"
```

You can also use `ansible_real_group_id` / `ansible_real_user_id` or `ansible_user_gid`/`ansible_user_uid` depending on your need.

Please don't forget double quotes around ansible expression.

See [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32455684/difference-between-real-user-id-effective-user-id-and-saved-user-id) for details on the difference between real and effective user

See [Ansible docs on system variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variables-discovered-from-systems-facts) for all available variables

Answer (score 0):

Try below.

```
  - name: chown to username you login and chmod as required
    file:
      path: $HOME/.kube/config
      owner: "{{ ansible_user }}"
      group: "{{ ansible_user }}"
      mode: 0644
```