# SUID Bit ignored on restart

Tags: linux, file-permissions

I have an issue with an SUID Bit being ignored after a reboot. The issue may very well lie with my understanding of the SUID Bit. I need to elevate the permissions of the python files in a directory because of the functions they perform. This is what I have done.

sudo find dir -type f -exec chmod u+s {} \; this is done in a python script using pexpect to supply the password. but I get the same issue when done via the command line.

if I then run ls -l -h gives the following (I get the same output when this is done after a restart)

-rwsrwxrwx 1 root root . . . filename.py

-rwsrwxrwx 1 root root . . . filename.py~

-rwSr--r-- 1 user user . . . filename.pyc

Setting SUID in the session works however as soon as a reboot occurs the SUID bit is still there but seems to be ignored. Now I thought setting the SUID bit via chmod meant that the user ran the program with the elevated permissions of root and that chmodding was persistent through restarts.

My question is is there a way to make a SUID bit survive a restart and not be ignored?

Any help on this would be great

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

> -rwsrwxrwx 1 root root . . . filename.py

Really? Even if this is a heavily firewalled workstation which nobody else has physical access to and you're the only physical user, leaving this lying around on your filesystem is a very bad idea.

> sudo find dir -type f -exec chmod u+s {} \;

So is this.

> using pexpect to supply the password

...meaning the root password is stored in cleartext file readable by a non-root user?

I'm very suspicious of your analysis. I have used setuid programs regularly (although not python scripts - I would expect then to [behave like any other setuid scripts](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/faq/part4/section-7.html) - although this [would not explain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8314012/setuid-bit-on-python-script-linux-vs-solaris) why they *ever* work as setuid) and never come across a problem like this. What do you think is changing at reboot? According to your post the permissions aren't changed - so if they really have stopped running as root this implies that something else is keeping track of whether it can run these scripts as a different user - and doing so in a way which does not survive reboots - the story is getting increasingly improbable.

Regardless the way to solve all the problems I've mentioned and probably fix your as well is to remove the setuid bit and invoke the programs via sudo.

Comment: with pexpect the user enters the password which is used immediately to perform sudo commands then ditched. The point of using SUID was to avoid having to have the user enter the sudo password every time certain functions need to be done. however you are probably right and another route should be sought. Cheers

Comment: `was to avoid having to have the user enter the sudo password` - that's what sudo's NOPASSWD config option is for - http://serverfault.com/questions/160581/how-to-setup-passwordless-sudo-on-linux